# Code-Rally Enter Race always Fails

Tags: code-rally

I can't enter a race, I always get an error saying "Unable to enter  on "

Is there an place where I can get any log info?

Any other sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check:

- What server are you trying to race on?
- What AI are you trying to race with? Intermediate or Agent?
- On the enter race window does your username appear on the bottom left next to a logout button?

The most likely cause of this is either you are not logged in (this should give a different error) or you are using an agent on a local Liberty server and something is preventing the server from starting. If it is an agent AI then you may see errors in your local Eclipse console - to make it visible in the code rally perspective go to window>show view>console. Any log output from the local Liberty server and your AI code will appear there, including any error messages.